# Node js and socket io with a PHP aapplication

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have been looking all over at various turtorials, videos and blogs but i havent seem to find an answer to my question:

Say you have a web application in a traditional framework (such as `cakephp` or other `PHPframework`)

Normally these will be build using MVC (Model view controller)

Now say we have our helloWorld application.

The first encouter for the client to the applicatoin might be: `www.helloWorld/Client/index`

According to the tutorials the of socket IO and node js the client will at this point make a connection to the server (the client connects to the socket).

The script that connects to the socket might be put into a layout file making sure that no matter where the user is he is always connected to the server.

Here comes the part i do not understand. if the client changes page wont he reconnect to the server at every page change? or is the nodejs and socket IO smart enough to know that it is on the same server? if so how do you make an application where the client is connected to a socket for as long as he is on your website?

Comment: On every page change the browser will close the existing connection to socket.IO and then will make a new connection on the new page (if you tell the browser to make a connection). If you want to use the same connection as long as a visitor is on the website, you have to avoid page reloads. Use AJAX to get page contents.

Comment: So everything on your site have to be loaded using Ajax? is there no other way to maintain a connection to the socket for the duration of the visit?

Comment: A browser will always close a connection.